# NGINX reload is not working properly

Tags: nginx

Recently i have done some config changes for access_logs directive in my nginx configuration file and then i reloaded the nginx server (./nginx -s reload), But the changes were not reflecting. Even i tried to disable the access_log (access_log off;) and reloaded server but still logs are generating.

The situation is like when i reload nginx configuration file sometimes the changes are reflecting and sometimes not. Kindly advise on this. I cant restart my nginx server as it is production env.

Note: The same changes are working properly in my preprod environment only facing issue in production environment.

Comment: Does it reload when you change something else (eg. Add new location in The config and then reload)?

Comment: Yeah, When i try to add some headers and if i reload means the changes are working fine.

Previously i have disabled the nginx access logs and today only i have enabled the access_logs for some testing. And when i tried to enable some custom log syntax there changes were not reflected so again i tried to disable the nginx access log using the directive (access_log off;) but still logs are generating and not able to stop. 

Note: Even i tried nginx syntax check (./nginx -t) and all syntax were fine.

Comment: Could you share the config file? Maybe you missed some semicolon or such... just append it to your post

Comment: http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=90525368949747132592

pls download the file from above link

Comment: Looks fine... And if you restart nginx instead of reload? Any difference?

Comment: Hi Keenan and Lesnik,

Actually this issue is regards with nginx reload only, I have executed the command nginx stop and start, then everything works perfectly. Thanks alot for everyone support :-)

Answer (score 0):

Actually this issue is with regards to nginx reload only, I have executed the command nginx stop and start, then everything works perfectly. Thanks alot for everyone support :-)